# Vending Machine Change Java

Tags: java, casting

I'm very new to Java. I'm getting an error. I know what's causing it is the `double(changeLeft)` but I need to get my result in a double so it shows proper change but I just have no clue how to do that.

I'm not allowed to use pennies. The smallest change is quarters.

I believe what I have to do is cast? But I'm honestly so lost.

ANY help/suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Cash {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    int itemCost = 0;
    int moneyInserted = 0;
    int changeLeft = 0;
    int hundred = 0;
    int fifty = 0;
    int twenty = 0;
    int ten = 0;
    int five = 0;
    int toonie = 0;
    int loonie = 0;
    double quarter = 0;

    System.out.println("Item cost?");
    itemCost = scanner.nextInt();

    System.out.println("Amount given?");
    moneyInserted = scanner.nextInt();

    changeLeft = moneyInserted - itemCost;

    hundred = changeLeft / 100;
    changeLeft = changeLeft % 100;

    fifty = changeLeft / 50;
    changeLeft = changeLeft % 50;

    twenty = changeLeft / 20;
    changeLeft = changeLeft % 20;

    ten = changeLeft / 10;
    changeLeft = changeLeft % 10;

    five = changeLeft / 5;
    changeLeft = changeLeft % 5;

    toonie = changeLeft / 2;
    changeLeft = changeLeft % 2;

    loonie = changeLeft / 1;
    changeLeft = changeLeft % 1;

    quarter = (double)changeLeft; 


    System.out.println("Change Due($): \n" +
             hundred + " Hundred\n" + fifty + " Fifty\n" + twenty +
             " Twenty\n" + ten + " Ten\n" + five + " Five\n" + toonie +
             " Toonie\n" + loonie + " Loonie\n" +
             quarter + " Quarter");        
    }
}
```

Comment: What is `x / 1`? What is the remainder of `x / 1`? (Hint: Math).

Comment: If you're working with money, then it should be a double. If you're getting counts from that double, then they can be ints. NB integer division is vastly different from double or floating point division.

Comment: If you're working with money, you can accept doubles as user input, but the doubles must be **immediately** converted to integer or long cents.  Floating point arithmetic is not precise enough for money calculations.

Answer (score 0):

You could update everything to doubles.  Note the Double.valueOf(String) from the scanner.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

double itemCost = 0;
double moneyInserted = 0;
double changeLeft = 0;
double hundred = 0;
double fifty = 0;
double twenty = 0;
double ten = 0;
double five = 0;
double toonie = 0;
double loonie = 0;
double quarter = 0;

System.out.println("Item cost?");
itemCost = Double.valueOf(scanner.next());

System.out.println("Amount given?");
moneyInserted = Double.valueOf(scanner.next());

changeLeft = moneyInserted - itemCost;

hundred = changeLeft / 100;
changeLeft = changeLeft % 100;

fifty = changeLeft / 50;
changeLeft = changeLeft % 50;

twenty = changeLeft / 20;
changeLeft = changeLeft % 20;

ten = changeLeft / 10;
changeLeft = changeLeft % 10;

five = changeLeft / 5;
changeLeft = changeLeft % 5;

toonie = changeLeft / 2;
changeLeft = changeLeft % 2;

loonie = changeLeft / 1;
changeLeft = changeLeft % 1;

quarter = (double)changeLeft; 


System.out.println("Change Due($): \n" +
         hundred + " Hundred\n" + fifty + " Fifty\n" + twenty +
         " Twenty\n" + ten + " Ten\n" + five + " Five\n" + toonie +
         " Toonie\n" + loonie + " Loonie\n" +
         quarter + " Quarter");


}
```